# How to fix menu bar and container in css when minimizing the page

Tags: html, css

Look at the picture, I don't know what the real problem is.

The search bar with the button and the box which have the text "PROFILE" give me a problem

[image]

```css
.profile{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
border-radius: 5px; 
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: 80px;
}
.srch{
width: 500px;
height: 30px;    
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid white;
margin-left: 150px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
.sub{
background: none;
border: 2px solid red;
border-radius: 2px;
color:white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
width: 100px;
height: 35px;    
}
```

Comment: Please tell me "pi" is not shorthand for "picture".

Comment: 1. Nothing to do with PHP. 2. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54860689/edit) and then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML (NOT PHP). Please click TIDY before exiting. Then you have a [mcve]

Comment: So you have an absolutely positioned box with fixed width. It is behaving as you ask it to.

Comment: please add a working code snippet.

Comment: please add some html markup

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

For the text

Answer (score 0):

Considerind CSS is used in HTML, why don't you try to use Bootstrap? It's really usefull, it can resize and re-position your element properly when resizing the window. And it does it responsevely. You can use its classes (like ) to do that.
Here, watch the layout grid documentation, it should work for your problem

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I did't exactly get you,

the code below hold the search bar with seacrch button.
if you want to place the search bar at above the profile column.make sure its inside the column.and remove the position:absolute; property and its right:; and top:; also.
use float:right;

```
.srch{
      position:relative;
     }

 .sub{
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
    }
```

have any questions,please don't hesitate to ask.